# JavaScript Math formula result

Tags: javascript, math

With help of others stackers I converted this Excel formula

```
=+G15*B15/(1-(1+G15)^(-H15))
```

into this javascript formula (given that G15=1.325%, B15=importe and H=plazo):

```
(importe * 0.01325) / (1 - (Math.pow((1 + importe), -plazo) ) );
```

Now, when in excel and javascript I calculate importe=10000 and plazo=144, in excel I get 155.93 and in javascript I get 132.5

I've been over this and lots of other formulas too much and there may be some silly mistake but I can't see... like reading a misspelled word you wrote and not spotting the typo.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There was a answer which I tried to select as the correct one but it's gone don't know why. The answer was that I was using "importe" for both G15 and G15

Comment: @Juan - the answer was deleted by the owner PitaJ. I don't have un-delete options, but if that was the solution, you can answer the question yourself.

Comment: @jvenema I know I can answer myswlf but I want to give credit to PitaJ  so I'll wait if s/he posts it again and if not I'll answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your desired calculation:
`=+G15*B15/(1-(1+G15)^(-H15))`
and instead of using your example of converted code:
`(importe * 0.01325) / (1 - (Math.pow((1 + importe), -plazo) ) )` that is equivalent of:

=B15*G15/(1-(1+***B15***)^(-H15))

so your formula should be:

`(0.01325 * importe) / (1 - (Math.pow((1 + 0.01325), -plazo)));`

Answer (score 0):

Try putting parentheses around the `G15*B15` in your excel formula and see if the answers match or not.

Answer (score 0):

[10001 ^ -144 = 9.857038937816808015251426789861755167080725836 × 10^-577](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10001%5E-144)

The result can't be representated correctly and will be "truncated" to 0. `132.5` equals to `(importe * 0.01325)`

[The Complete Javascript Number Reference](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/The_Complete_Javascript_Number_Reference)